# How to Install Ubuntu 12.10 on the GPT ?

Tags: boot

I have installed Win7 first and I created GPT.

Unfortunately, when I try to install Ubuntu 12.10, in the GParted, it just show all my HDD haven't partition.

In the Window I still see the C,D,E....

Why was that happend ?

Can I fix it or I must format ?

I really want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/376607/problems-installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-7-gpart-shows-unallocated-s