# Ubuntu after Windows 7 disk unrecognized

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, partitioning

I've formatted the disk and installed Windows 7 on a pre-installed Windows 8. (UEFI - disabled secure boot)
When I try to install Ubuntu from a live CD, it cant recognize my HDD partitions, not even trying to allocate a partition on ext4, NTFS in GParted live and on windows disc manager. Ubuntu simply can't see the HDD partitions nor the installation of windows, I tried to do something with fixparts but don't know exactly what to do.
Here i put a screenshot.
[image: my partitions]
Edit:
Here I list my partitions:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
```

NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL                  MOUNTPOINT

sda

├─sda1 ntfs     Reservado pelo Sistema

├─sda2 ntfs

└─sda3 ext4

sdb
└─sdb1 vfat                            /cdrom

sr0
loop0  squashfs                        /rofs

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -l
```

NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda     8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk

sda1    8:1    0   100M  0 part

sda2    8:2    0  97.6G  0 part

sda3    8:3    0 368.1G  0 part

sdb     8:16   0   3.7G  0 disk

sdb1    8:17   0   3.7G  0 part /cdrom

sr0    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

loop0   7:0    0 962.1M  1 loop /rofs

Ubuntu's Gparted give me a warning when opened:

> /dev/sda contains GPT signatures indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it has a fake msdos partition table as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted? Is this a GPT partition table?

Comment: Please start the Ubuntu live system and provide the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo fdisk -l`. A screenshot of GParted might help too. If your hard drive(s) aren't listed there at all, provide the output of `sudo dmesg`. You can copy and paste command output on the terminal. Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems Installing Ubuntu 13.10 Alongside Windows 7 - gpart shows unallocated space](http://askubuntu.com/questions/376607/problems-installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-7-gpart-shows-unallocated-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to boot the LiveCD in no-EFI mode, since you've installed Windows in legacy mode.

Execute `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` and try converting to MBR and then rewriting the partion table under Recovery/transformation options.

Comment: Solved! Thank you! Now Im going to test the boot.

Comment: I've got new problems with the boot, updated grub and it doesn't worked to enter windows. I rebooted and recovered windows with the boot disk, and finally it worked! Thanks a lot!